# Windows Workflow Foundation - schedule activities to run at certain times

Tags: workflow-foundation, scheduling

I'm evaluating whether WF would be a good fit for a design I'm working on. I'm in that chicken-and-egg conundrum where I don't want to invest too much time in learning all the details until I have a good idea that it's going to be suitable.

The one thing that I can't seem to find much on that could be significant is scheduling. And by that I mean scheduling of activities to start at a certain time.

E.g. I have a workflow that, on starting, executes the first two activities - but then must wait until, say, 9am the next day before continuing.

I realise I could achieve the same effect by splitting this into two workflows - with the second triggered by, say, a scheduled task. But that would lose much of the benefits of having workflows in the first place - such as seamless persistence of state between activities and guaranteed ordering.

So is there a way to achieve this in a single workflow? Preferably built in to WF (e.g. a WaitUntil activity) - but an alternative might be that the workflow sleeps until recieving an external prod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Delay activity where you calculate the duration will do that just fine.

Comment: I had been thinking about that. So can that be used to work the workflow up at the right time?

Comment: Yes, but it depends a bit on your hosting scenario as well. Using a workflow service hosted in the AppFabric makes things easiest. Using the WorkflowApplication you are responsible to make sure it is loaded and ready to run.

Comment: We would be hosting it ourselves. Thanks for your help.

Comment: With Appfabric I was referring to Windows Server AppFabric not the Azure version which doesn't include workflow at the moment. So you still need to host it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish this if you host your Workflow in IIS on WCF with an delay activity adding SQL Persistance to the workflow as well