# Time based triggers in Windows Workflow Foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm looking at using Windows WF to implement a system, which includes the need to support workflows that have either transitions or activities that need to be scheduled to execute at either a certain date/time in the future, or after a certain period of time has elapsed.

I found a question along these lines already:

[Windows Workflow Foundation - schedule activities to run at certain times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837950/windows-workflow-foundation-schedule-activities-to-run-at-certain-times)

Which suggests using the Delay task and calculating the duration of the delay in order to proceed at the required time. I have a few additional questions however, but don't have enough reputation to add comments so I'm posting a secondary question:

How can I implement it such that it can recover from a crash? For example, let's say the task is currently in the delay task and the process hosting the workflow engine crashes. When it is restarted, will it resume waiting in the delay task, and trigger at the time required? Do you have to do something special to get this to happen?

Another question is, again let's say a workflow instance is already mid-way through the delay task. At that point, you suddenly need to alter the time/date at which the workflow progresses to the next activity/task. Is it possible to programmatically update the duration on the in-play delay task to effect this?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you store started instances in the SQL Store, you can add Persist activity each time you want to force save it. After crash activity will continue from last persist.
2. You can replace single big Delay with While cycle. In condition you check if you need to delay or not, in body you place Delay activity with short interval. You can add persist after that short Delay and instance will not wait full time again after crash (it depends on While condition, you need to store somewhere state of your instances. For example in variable).